# DKMS failing to complete in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, updates, linux-kernel

After my last attempt to run an update with `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade` I got into a never returning update step (see below). So far I can only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> but it will be triggered again after every update. If I stop it too harshly, e.g. restarting, then all the update locks are left and I have to delete them manually. How can I get rid of this never-ending loop?

```
-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  bcmwl
Version: 6.20.155.1+bdcom
Kernel:  3.5.0-40-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

wl.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.5.0-40-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod....

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.20.155.1+bdcom
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new bcmwl-6.20.155.1+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 3.5.0-40-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.5.0-40-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.5.0-40-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
_ <<<<< never comes back
```

How do I prevent DKMS from hijacking `apt-get`? or how can I find which module is leading DKMS to hang?

Comment: do you have `3.5.0-40-generic` kernel headers installed?